# database design for a car database web and desktop application

Tags: java, sql, database

i want to make a project to view any car technical and performance specs such as carfolio.com and zeperfs.com

i would like to design a desktop and web application but i wanted to ask specifically about the database design

should i start with the database? and what type of database should i use ?

sql or oracle or file system //

to be more specific my project must view any car from any manufacturer you want all specs such as engine power torque // speed // gas millage // wheel base ...etc.

thanks

Comment: Yes, start with the DB and use a DB you like (no file system). No recommendations here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to start with the data model. If you have a model it is easy to create a db schema out of it.